# Expected response code 250 but got code “”, with message “” Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, email, outlook, laravel-5

I'm trying to configure Outlook account of my client to send emails but getting error. This error occur only when I use Outlook account but when set my own Gmail account it work perfectly and send emails. Following is my ENV file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp-mail.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=sales@5starresortsplus.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

What was the issue? I don't know if I'm missing anything or it's just configuration mistakes in ENV file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution how to configure Outlook account to send email so I'm posting my solution in case anyone need it. Following are the correct smtp settings for outlook, only need to change host:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=sales@5starresortsplus.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```